# Prove $M$(Helix) is a sub-manifold of dimension $1$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

> Let $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^+$. Consider the circular Helix  $M\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ the image of $\psi:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^3,t\to(\alpha\cos t,\alpha\sin t,\beta t)$.
>
> Prove $M$ is a sub-manifold of dimension $1$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have no ideia how to prove this. I have already proven $\psi$ is an injective immersion. I think I need to find a map $F:M\to\mathbb{R}$, which I happen to found $F:M\to\mathbb{R},(\alpha\cos t,\alpha\sin t,\beta t)\to(\alpha^2+\beta t^2)$. However this would imply the dimension to be 3-1=2, which is wrong.

**Question:**

How can I solve the question? Am I proceeding well?

Comment: Why do you want to find such an $M$? Isn't being an injective (and proper) immersion enough?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown            I am being asked to prove M is a sub-manifold of dimesion 1. The question follows the one that asks me to prove that $M$ is an injective immersion.                                I want to compute the mass and the centre of gravity.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "why do you want to find such an $F$". Surely its centre of mass is $(0,0,\beta\pi$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown                          There is a theorem that states that the $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^{n-m}$ such that : $F(p)=0, F^{-1}F(p)\cap M$ is an open set of $M$. F is a submersion in each point $F^{-1}F(p)\cap M$ such that $rank(F,x)=n-m,\:\:\forall x\in F^{-1}F(p)\cap M$. As I know on this problem that $n=3$, I would find out $m$, the dimension of $M$. These results follow from the constant characteristic theorem. Thanks for your replies insofar!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you think the image of $F$ is instead $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: If you want an $F$ why not $(x-\alpha\cos(z/\beta),y-\alpha\sin(z/\beta))$? But doing this via submersions rather than immersions is the hard way.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Do you think I defined the function correctly? Do you think it is instead $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^2,(\alpha\cos t,\alpha\sin t,\beta t)\to(\alpha^2+\beta t^2)$. All I did was to sum each vector component $(x,y,z)$, this way $x^2+y^2+z^2$
Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

As defined, the Helix $M = \psi([0, 2\pi])$ is not a submanifold of $\Bbb R^3$, because it is not a topological manifold. Indeed, $\psi$ is an homeomorphism from $[0,2\pi]$ onto its image $M$, because it is continuous, injective, and goes from a compact space to a Hausdorff space. However, $[0, 2\pi]$ is not a topological manifold (it's a manifold with boundary), so $M$ cannot be a topological manifold.

Maybe you want to take the open Helix $M = \psi((0, 2\pi))$, $\psi : (0, 2\pi) \rightarrow M$.
The easiest way is not to work with submersions but with immersions. Indeed, using the definition of a submanifold for one direction and constant rank theorem for the other, one can prove the following :

> $M \subset \Bbb R^n$ is a submanifold of dimension $m \leq n$ if and only if for all $p \in M$, there exists an open set $V \subset R^m$, an open set $W$, $p \in W \subset \Bbb R^n$, and an injective immersion $\phi : V \subset \Bbb R^m \rightarrow W \subset \Bbb R^n$ such that $\phi(V) = W \cap M$ and $\phi$ is an homeomorphism from $V \rightarrow W \cap M$.

In your case, set $M$ to be the open Helix, $m = 1$, $V = (0, 2\pi)$, $n = 3$, $W = \Bbb R^3$, $\phi = \psi$ (here we use the same sets $V$, $W$, and the same function $\phi$ for all $p \in M$).